# Using existence and uniqueness to prove boundedness of a function far from initial condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y$ be the solution to $y'=-x^3(e^{y^2}-e)$ satisfying $y(0)=0.5$. Prove $y$ is bounded.

My proof:
$y_1\equiv 1$ and $y\equiv -1$ are two solutions. If $y(x)$ satisfy $y(x_0)=1$, then $y(x_0)=y_1(x_0)=1$ would contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs. Therefore, $y(x)$ cannot intersect $y=\pm 1$ which implies that we must have $-1<y<1$.

My questions are:

> 1. Since the equation is nonlinear, is there anything that can guarantee that the solution $y(x)$ is defined for any value of $x$? (and not only in a small neighborhood of $x=0$ where the initial condition is specified?
> 2. Following (1) - what prevents a function $y$ from being not bounded, and having a removable singularity at a point $(x_0,1)$ from being a solution? See next figure.

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

Yes - it follows as a consequence of the full statement of the existence and uniqueness theorem. The local time of existence of $y' = f(x,y), y(x_0) = y_0$ coming from the Picard-Lindelof theorem is $\mathcal{O}(1/L(y_0))$, where $L(y_0)$ is the local Lipschitz constant. Naively, to extend the solution beyond the interval $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ you'd use Picard-Lindelof again at a point $x_1 \in (x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)$ to construct a local solution starting at $x_1$. The problem is that because in general $f$ might not have the same local Lipschitz constant at $y(x_1)$, you can run into a case where the length by which you can extend your solution shrinks every time you run this argument, and ultimately you fail to extend your solution to all $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

But if we also know *a priori* that $y$ is globally bounded between $[A,B]$, and we can show that $f$ satisfies a *global* Lipschitz bound $|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| \leq L|y_1-y_2|$ for all $y_1,y_2\in[A,B]$, then we can actually use the *same* Lipschitz constant at each step. This means that you can extend your solution by a timestep of the *same* length $\mathcal{O}(1/L)$ every time, and if you carry this out indefinitely you will obtain a solution defined for all $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$. In this particular case, since you already know the solution with $y(0) = 0.5$ is bounded between $\pm 1$, this argument applies and the solution is in fact global.

Your second idea doesn't work for two reasons:

1. The most salient reason is that if your function isn't defined at $x_0$, it certainly can't satisfy *any* differential equations at $x_0$.
2. You could try to modify your example to a function with a more arbitrary discontinuity at $x_0$, but if $y$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ it is also nondifferentiable at $x_0$, so $y'(x_0)$ is undefined and $y$ cannot be said to satisfy the differential equation at $x_0$.

---

Addendum:

There is a slightly subtle point in that $f(x,y)$ has a Lipschitz constant that is only global in $y$ for $x$ in bounded intervals. To obtain the exact dependence, write
$$
|f(x,y_1(x)) - f(x,y_2(x))| \leq |x|^3|e^{y_1(x)^3}-e^{y_2(x)^3}|.
$$
Let $M = \max_{y\in[0,1]} 3y^2e^{y^3}$. Then by the mean value theorem, if $0\leq y_1,y_2\leq 1$ (which we can guarantee for solutions of the IVP), we have
$$
|e^{y_1(x)^3}-e^{y_2(x)^3}| \leq M|y_1(x)-y_2(x)|.
$$
Therefore the Lipschitz bound is given by
$$
|f(x,y_1(x)) - f(x,y_2(x))| \leq M|x|^3\|y_1 - y_2\|_\infty.
$$
The constant $L = M|x|^3$ does depend on $x$, which might make it sound like we could run into issues extending the solution. But this turns out not to be a problem, because a corollary of Picard-Lindelof is that ODEs have a very simple blowup dichotomy. This goes by the name of the maximal Cauchy development, and it essentially states that for functions $f$ satisfying Lipschitz bounds on bounded sets, the corresponding unique solution $y$ to the ODE either blows up in finite time or is globally defined. In other words, suppose $(a,b)$ is the maximal set of $x$ for which the solution $y$ to the IVP is defined. If $b < \infty$, then this can only occur because $\lim_{x\to b} y(x) = \pm\infty$; likewise for $a > -\infty$. But in your specific case, we have a priori that $y$ is globally bounded. Therefore we cannot have $b < \infty$ nor $a > -\infty$, since those would imply $y$ is unbounded.

As for the proof of this statement on the maximal Cauchy development, and the fact that the dependence of $L = M|x|^3$ on $x$ is actually not a problem, I will refer you to [these notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/254a-notes-1-local-well-posedness-of-the-navier-stokes-equations/), Theorem 8 and Exercise 12. These should cover essentially everything one needs to know about Picard-Lindelof for ODEs.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! Can you maybe recommend a good reference for a book/online resource that states the existence and uniqueness theorem together with the "The local time of existence of $y′=f(x,y),y(x0)=y0$ coming from the Picard-Lindelof theorem is $O(1/L(y0))$ , where $L(y0)$  is the local Lipschitz constant." part?

Comment: It is an artifact of the proof of Picard-Lindelof. Careful examination of any proof of P-L will show you that the time of existence can be bounded from below as a function of the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try and go over the proof.

Comment: One thing I still can't figure it is - why if the solution satisfying $y(0)=0.5$ is bounded between 0 and 1 this implies that the Lipschitz constant is "uniform"?

Comment: just to elaborate on my previous comment- since $y$ is bounded, we can say that $|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)|<|f(x,y_2)|+|f(x,y_1)| <= 2\cdot |x^3|\cdot |1-e|$. This still doesn't imply that $f$ is Lipschitz, and hence I cannot understand how to apply the argument you mentioned in the second paragraph. Hope you'll be able to help me out in this. Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.John Added some additional material, see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Just notice the exponent of the original function $f$ is $y^2$ and not $y^3$. Do you happen to know which ODE book contains the "maximal Cauchy development" theorem you mentioned? I will be happy to read more about it

Comment: The notes I linked mention it and provide a proof.

Comment: Thank you. I will thoroughly go over it

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer to your first question. The solution to the differential equation $y'=-x^3(e^{y^2}-e)$ that satisfies the initial condition $y(0)=0.5$ is given in implicit form by
$$
-\frac{x^4}{4}=\int_{0.5}^y\frac{du}{e^{u^2}-e}=:f(y). \tag{1}
$$
Since $f(y)$ is continuous in the interval $[0.5,1)$, $f(0.5)=0$, and $\lim_{y\to 1^{-}}f(y)=-\infty$, for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ there exists $y\in[0.5,1)$ such that $f(y)=-\frac{x^4}{4}$. This implies that $y$ is bounded.

Comment: thank you for that!